# Geometric series pentagonal numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The pentagonal numbers are the sequence

```
1,5,12,22,35
```

What is the difference between the 99th pentagonal number and the 100th? The answer is 298.

But, if I were to calculate the difference should be 3 since the formula is

```
99(3) + 4 = 301
100(3)+ 4 = 304
```

Why is the answer 298?

[image]

Comment: Your formula is not right for pentagonal numbers.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number) I find that $p_n=(3n^2-n)/2$. What is the base of your formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:
$$\begin{align}p_2-p_\color{red}1&=4=a_\color{red}1\\
p_3-p_\color{red}2&=7=a_\color{red}2\\
p_4-p_\color{red}3&=10=a_\color{red}3\\
p_5-p_\color{red}4&=13=a_\color{red}4\\
&\ \ \vdots \\
p_{99}-p_{\color{red}{98}}&=4+97\cdot 3=a_{\color{red}{98}}\\
p_{100}-p_{\color{red}{99}}&=4+98\cdot 3=a_{\color{red}{99}}=298.\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The formula for pentagonal number is

$$p_n=\frac{3n^2-n}2$$

$$p_n-p_{n-1}=\frac{3n^2-3(n-1)^2-1}2=\frac{3(2n-1)-1}{2}=\frac{6n-4}{2}=3n-2$$

I am puzzled how do you end up with something similar to $4+3n$. This is not an arithmetic progression. Also, it is not a geometric sequence as well.

Comment: I have updated the post with the full question and explanation.

Comment: I see, the difference is indeed an arithmetic progression. so yup, you just have to figure out how many times has $3$ been added.

Comment: I am getting confused over here. shouldnt the 99th and 100th number have a difference of 3 instead of 298?

Comment: $3$ is the difference of two consecutive difference. We are interested in consecutive difference. To help you understand, you shouldn't work with $99$th and $100$th first, you should work on the $4$th and $5$th number first.